# Universally weak/feeble name for a prey species

Tags: creature-design, aliens, language, names

In many languages words have similar patterns, even with different language roots, e.i. Indo-European or Sino-Tibetan. An example being the words for the universal family unit of a male and female parent, Mother/Mom and Father/Dad in American-English, and Mǔqīn/Māmā and Fùqīn/Bà. Now to the question.

What would be a universally weak/feeble/whateverdafuq sounding name for a species that would conform to human language patterns when making names for shit. Also assume these creatures have a near identical anatomy to humans, meaning they would they ways in which they communicate is virtually identical.

Also, sorry if this really isn't the type of questions that are meant for this place; this is my first time using this site

Comment: There's no universal word for "shit", but the concept is there, "shit", "trash", you call it. This kind of question can be on-topic if you can narrow down your language of choice. However, be careful with your wording, as this kind of question is usually "opinion-based". I'd suggest you post your question on [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) first, ask for inputs, then edit this post when you're ready.

Comment: In the title you ask for prey, in the body you ask for.. well.. what you ask for... can you clarify?

Comment: This is an impossible question to answer.  Words sound "universal" based on linguistic crossover as cultrue groups collided.  The earlier the collision, the more "universal" the word merely because it was borrowed.  If any word was truly universal based on the human experience, it would be the word for "hot" and it would be pronounced "OW!" throughout the world.  It isn't.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to focus on **prey** over **weak**.

**Plants** are easily and universally consumed. While not prey per se, this is useful to keep in mind.

**Herbivores** are universally prey to some predator or other.

Prey have eyes set on the sides of their heads (in contrast, predators on the fronts of their heads.) Prey do not tend to have sharp teeth or claws. Prey might more often reproduce heavily and live in packs; their survival depends on a numbers game.

With those sorts of considerations, and depending on what you mean by "name" (scientific? Silly? Obvious? Clever?) you might consider names like:

Vegetators (as in, vegetables)
Sideviewers (as opposed to frontviewers, eg humans)
Homo herbivalis (as opposed to Homo sapiens)
Hominin adontilis (toothless upright ape)

etc. I like the last one best.